# mingw-w64-v2.0.6.tar.gz - define environment variables path 

Tags: c++, eclipse, environment-variables, eclipse-juno, mingw-w64

I download the latest version of minGW  - mingw-w64-v2.0.6.tar.gz . Then I extract in into `C:\MinGW` . As I saw in some articles, now I have to define the `path` under environment variables  .
In  `C:\MinGW` now have -

[image]

I tried to set the variable value of path as `C:\MinGW` , but when I do in eclipse juno build path for some project I get  -

```
make all 
Cannot run program "make": Launching failed

Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
```

**EDIT:**

I downloaded GCC+binutils 64-bit   ,exctract to `c:\mingw64` , change the path to `c:\mingw64\bin` and  changed the build command to `mingw32-make`.
Now when I build the project I get error  -

```
mingw32-make all 
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

**2nd EDIT :**

finally I succeeded to run a project by chose -

[image]

Note that it must uncheck the `show project type and toolchians only if they are supported on the platform` otherwise it not let to chose **Executable** Project type  . In addition the build command should be stay on "Use default build command" .

Comment: Do you understand what you downloaded?

Comment: Apparently compiler for cpp , not  ?

Comment: No, you downloaded the source code for mingw-w64. You need a separate compiler and toolchain (make, etc.) to build the code yourself (or just use rubenvbs personal builds).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You downloaded the source package.

You need a toolchain (GCC+binutils and maybe make/gdb). Those are located here:

- [32-bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/)
- [64-bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/)

I recommend my (rubenvb) Personal builds. They are tidy, full-featured and up to date.

After extracting the toolchain anywhere (say, `D:\`), add `D:\mingw64\bin` or `D:\mingw32\bin` to `PATH`. Or double-click on the batch scripts I include with my latest builds and it'll be done for you.

Note that you'll need to set up Eclipse for MinGW compilation, which means using `mingw32-make`, not `make`.

Lastly, I also suggest using MinGW-w64's support channels (forum and mailing list; please subscribe before posting to mingw-w64-public) in the future. I linger there, among other generally nice and helpful people.

Comment: I personally vouch for up-to-date. I don't even look anywhere else these days. Didn't you also include clang these days, or am I misremembering?

Comment: I also have a 32-bit Clang. Be sure to read the Readme displayed by the SourceForge download page in the clang-3.1 directory. You need a special GCC version to effectively use Clang.

Comment: @rubenvb which version chose under rubenvb ? gcc-4.7-release ? I have 64 bit .

Comment: @URL87 I see you already posted to the MinGW-w64 forums. Let's continue this there.